# EF load related collection partially

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

What I'm trying to achieve is return a list of Categories (in JSON) with the latest (Top 1) modified product in it.

Say I have a Product & Category classes.

```
Class Category{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Product> Products {get;set;}
   public Product FirstProduct { get { return          Products.OrderByDescending(p=>p.Modified).FirstOrDefault;}
```

and a MVC api controller that does the following

```
....
return db.Categories.Include(p=>p.Products.OrderByDescending(m=>m.Modified).Take(1).FirstOrDefault());
.....
```

But that doesn't seem to work...

The expected result is something like this (I actually need only the Name and the FirstProduct columns):

```
[
{Name : "Category1", FirstProduct : {Name : "Product1"}, Products : [{Name: "Product1}]
{Name : "Category2", FirstProduct : {Name : "Product1"}, Products : [{Name: "Product1}]
{Name : "Category3", FirstProduct : {Name : "Product1"}, Products : [{Name: "Product1}]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A projection might be a solution:

```
IEnumerable<Category> categories = db.Categories
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Category = c,
        FirstProduct = c.Products
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Modified)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => x.Category);
```

If you don't need all properties you could project only the needed properties, for example instead of `Category = c` you would use `CategoryName = c.Name` or add a `Select` between  `OrderByDescending` and `FirstOrDefault` to project properties of `Product`.

Comment: Wouldn't it have the same problem,  that products aren't loaded ? cause my initial problem of "firstProduct" getter not working was caused by that (products collection not being loaded and resulting in null at firstProduct getter

Comment: @Marty: If the relationship between `Category` and `Product` is one-to-many (not many-to-many) it should work because EF will add the `FirstProduct` to the collection in `Category` automatically (that's called *relationship fixup*).